# PHP - Get next draw date (Lottery)

Tags: php, if-statement

I am planning to make a lottery with PHP.
Now I want to output the next draw date with PHP.

The draw should start every Thuesday and thursday at 7 PM,
and now I want to output the next draw date for the client:

Monday,Friday,Saturday,Sunday - Next draw date is Thuesday

Thuesday - Next draw date is Thuesday (today) if it is not 7 PM otherwise the next draw date is thursday.

Wednesday - Next draw date is the thursday

thursday - Next draw date is thursday (today) if it is not 7 PM otherwise the next draw date is Thuesday .

Now I want to create an if-Statement which prints out the correct date for every condition - for example for Wednesday the next date for Thursday and so on.

I really tried it serveral times but it is always a mess and not working.

Edit:
Is it working like that?

```
 if(date('D') == "Tue" && new DateTime() < new DateTime("19:00:00")){
    //Dienstag
    return date('F j , Y');

}elseif(date('D') == "Tue" && new DateTime() > new DateTime("19:00:00")){
    //Donnerstag
    return date('F j , Y', strtotime('next thursday'));


}elseif(date('D') == "Thu" && new DateTime() < new DateTime("19:00:00")){
    //Donnerstag
    return date('F j , Y');

}elseif(date('D') == "Thu" && new DateTime() > new DateTime("19:00:00")){
    //Donnerstag
    return date('F j , Y', strtotime('next tuesday'));



}elseif(date('D') == 'Mon' || date('D') == 'Fri' || date('D') == 'Sat' || date('D') == 'Sun') {
    //Dienstag
    return date('F j , Y', strtotime('next tuesday'));


} elseif(date('D') == 'Wed') {
    //Donnerstag
    return date('F j , Y', strtotime('next thursday'));
}
```

Comment: I need to check the days because the next drawing date depends on the date to day and the time (DateTime()) - if today's date is Tuesday but it is after 7 PM the next drawing date is thursday

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime` will automatically use the current unix timestamp to base your string annotation off of.

Just do:

```
$date = strtotime("+7 day");
echo date('M d, Y', $date);
```

I think this should do it.
Documentation: [documentation](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.strtotime.php)

Comment: strtotime('next thursday') is actually working, I tried it!

Comment: More or less, I am not sure if my code is working because you can't simulate the time, that is why i am asking if the code "looks" correct

Comment: Just modify the draw day.If it works for today,it will work for everyday of the week